# How to trigger downstream pipeline in gitlab ci using different yml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to use specific yml file to trigger downstream project.

So, I have following in upstream project:

```
trigger-integration-test:
  stage: test
  trigger:
      project: platform/api-testing
```

but it uses .gitlab-ci.yml in the root directory but I need to use /path/to/different/.diffferent-gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a [parent-child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html) here:

```
trigger-integration-test:
  stage: test
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'platform/api-testing'
        file: '/path/to/different/.diffferent-gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Comment: This will unfortunately only include the job in that YML file in the current project. It does not trigger the job in the context of the downstream project. I have yet to find a solution.